# Add logic to else in case expression to handle nulls

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, case

I have created a query that uses a `case` expression with `substring` on a column of data in SQL to return values based on what's returned. If none of the data from the `substring` matches what I put in then I use `else` to just display the data from another column.  This if fine unless it ends up being `null`.  Is there a way I can use in `if` statement or something inside the `else` to handle `nulls`?

Example

```
select 
  case
  SUBSTRING(Name,3,3)
  when 'USA' Then 'United States'
  when 'CAN' Then 'Canada'
  when 'AUS' Then 'Australia'
  when 'BGT' Then 'Bogata'
  else SiteName
  end as 'Location Name'
from V_DevLocationData
```

And I was trying to find a way to handle nulls in "SiteName" if the `case` expression doesn't find any matches.  I have tried

```
else (IF SiteName is Null THEN RETURN substring(Name0,3,3) ELSE RETURN SiteName END)
```

I can't get it work though.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest:

```
select (case when substring(Name, 3, 3) = 'USA' Then 'United States'
             when substring(Name, 3, 3) = 'CAN' Then 'Canada'
             when substring(Name, 3, 3) = 'AUS' Then 'Australia'
             when substring(Name, 3, 3) = 'BGT' Then 'Bogata'
             when SiteName is not null then SiteName
             else substring(Name, 3, 3) 
        end) as Location_Name
from V_DevLocationData ;
```

You can also use your method with `coalesce()`:

```
select (case substring(Name, 3, 3)
             when 'USA' Then 'United States'
             when 'CAN' Then 'Canada'
             when 'AUS' Then 'Australia'
             when 'BGT' Then 'Bogata'
             else coalesce(SiteName, substring(Name, 3, 3)) 
        end) as Location_Name
from V_DevLocationData ;
```

Comment: Will the first example enumerate through all the first substring when clauses and exits if it finds one first then only resort to site name if it doesnt find a substring match?

Comment: @Keets . . . A `case` expression stops at the first match.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ISNULL Function as below:

```
select 
  case
  SUBSTRING(Name,3,3)
  when 'USA' Then 'United States'
  when 'CAN' Then 'Canada'
  when 'AUS' Then 'Australia'
  when 'BGT' Then 'Bogata'
  else ISNULL(SiteName,substring(Name0,3,3))
  end as 'Location Name'
from V_DevLocationData
```